# Is that possible to implement bridge to send USDT from statemint to other parachains?

Tags: python

I have tried to explore https://github.com/polkascan/py-substrate-interface, but didn't find any example, so I am wondering if I want to send asset like USDT from statemine parachain to another parachain?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a bridge at all, Polkadot includes a message transport protocol for its parachains. I'd check out Subscan's [XCM explorer](https://statemine.subscan.io/xcm_transfer) to look at examples of asset transfers and how those transactions are constructed. For example, here is a transfer of some USDT from [Statemine to Moonriver](https://statemine.subscan.io/xcm_transfer/kusama-1000-2978330-5).

Answer (score 1):

Like Joe is saying, you need to open HRMP channels and then send an XCM.
You can see the actual XCM Joe referenced here:

- https://statemine.subscan.io/extrinsic/2978330-2?event=2978330-5

More info here:

- https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/parachains/add-hrmp-channels
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UfxU3hUprKo